# MongoDB / meteor query match on json object inside an array?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, nosql

I am struggling to query on a json object inside an array of json objets, is this possible? if not any alternatives you would recommend?

```
availability : [{
              date: date,
              times: [{
                start:timeAvail[timeStart],
                end: timeAvail[timeEnd]
              }]
            }];
```

I want to query on date to get all objects with a certain date and **get the array of all objects that match like [{date: x, time: [y]}]**
I've tried this but doesn't return:

```
Collection.find({availability: {$in: [{date: "2016/10/2"}]}}).fetch()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Collection.find({'availability.date': {$eq: new Date("2016/10/02").toISOString}}).fetch()
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Is there anyway to have it return only the date & times elements matched instead of the whole tuple?

Comment: yes, see here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/